# Find closest, future date of given number of weeks cycle

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

Let's say I have a:

```
start_date = '2020-01-06'
```

and `date(now())`

And I want to find closest future date, starting from now that is a multiplication of 4 (n) (or another number) weeks cycle from `start_date`

Expected output as for today would be `'2020-03-02'`

I can't came up with any smart idea to check for it.

I'll highly appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Post expected output.

Comment: I did, for n = 4 and as for today, result would be '2020-03-02'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do date arithmetics:

- compute the difference between now and the "anchor" date
- divide that by 7 (days per week) and 4 (weeks)
- take the next integer value from the result
- multiply by 4 and 7, then add that number of days to the current date

In SQL:

```
date'2020-01-06' + ceil((current_date - date'2020-01-06')::numeric / 4 / 7)::int * 4 * 7
```

**[Dremo on DB Fiddlde](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=07b90f1e3f1aaab1c9a38f634a99cc83)**:

```
with t as (select date'2020-01-06' anchor, 4 n)
select 
    anchor,
    n,
    current_date,
    anchor + ceil((current_date - anchor)::numeric / n / 7)::int * n * 7 next_date
from t
```

```
anchor     |  n | current_date | next_date 
:--------- | -: | :----------- | :---------
2020-01-06 |  4 | 2020-02-10   | 2020-03-02
```